# d3 determine the end point of the path of the last element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have pieces of a pie, I am tracking pieces less than 10% - I draw an additional path with them and I need to draw a line up from the last path, like this:

[image]

Here's an example:

```js
const height = 300,
  width = 300,
  margin = 30,
  data = [{
      browser: "Google Chrome",
      rate: 42.52
    },
    {
      browser: "Firefox",
      rate: 16.23
    },
    {
      browser: "Opera",
      rate: 12.6
    },
    {
      browser: "Internet Explorer",
      rate: 8.97
    },
    {
      browser: "Yandex Browser",
      rate: 9.12
    },
    {
      browser: "Other",
      rate: 10.56
    }
  ];

const color = d3.scale.category10();

const radius = Math.min(width - 2 * margin, height - 2 * margin) / 2;

const arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .innerRadius(0);

const arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius + 5)
  .innerRadius(radius + 3);

const pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.rate;
  });

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");
const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.browser);
  });

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc2)
  .style("display", d => d.data.rate < 10 ? 'block' : 'none');

g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.browser;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The outer circle is drawn from a variable arc2.

Ultimately pieces less than 10% must be carried up:

[image]

Comment: What does the line do if the arc ends up behind the circle?

Comment: @Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen, added image, ultimately pieces less than 10% must be carried up

Comment: Any ideas? Need help

Comment: Bump,
Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310862/display-the-text-at-the-end-of-the-arc-in-d3-js)

1. get the `d` attribute from the last element
2. ust `path.split("L")[1].split("A")[0]` to get the position of the endpoint of the arc.

   ```
    g.filter(d=>d.data.rate < 10) // using filter to only draw what we need
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "arc2")
            .attr("d", arc2)

    let last_arc2 = d3.selectAll(".arc2")[0][d3.selectAll(".arc2")[0].length-1]

    let last_arc2_end = d3.select(last_arc2).attr("d").split("L")[1].split("A")[0]

    let last_arc2_end_x = last_arc2_end.split(",")[0],
        last_arc2_end_y = last_arc2_end.split(",")[1]
    g.append("line")
            .attr("x1", last_arc2_end_x)
            .attr("x2", last_arc2_end_x)
            .attr("y1", last_arc2_end_y)
            .attr("y2", last_arc2_end_y-20)
            .style("stroke", "black")
   ```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/s2k8dw96/29/)