# How to add image at the end of Arc

Tags: d3.js, automatic-ref-counting

I am using d3 js i have to show image at the end of the arc how can i achieve that below is my example

[image]

```js
var total_codes = 8;
var remaining_codes = 4;
var issued = total_codes - remaining_codes;
var coloursArray = ["#128ED2", "#dadada"];
var dataset = {
  privileges: [issued, remaining_codes]
};

var width = 160,
  height = 160,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(coloursArray);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 30)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie(dataset.privileges))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc);
path.transition().duration(750);

var point = path.node().getPointAtLength(path.node().getTotalLength() / 2);

svg.append("image")
  .attr("cx", point.x)
  .attr("cy", point.y)
  .attr({
    "xlink:href": "http://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckf41wu0g00082c6g6bzer2cc/images/pacman_active_icon.png", //nothing visible
    width: 35,
    height: 36
  });

svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".0em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "inside")
  .html(function() {
    return "<tspan x='0' dy='0em'>External</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>Privileges</tspan>";
  }); // Add your code here
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut"></div>
```

Comment: maybe a relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310862/display-the-text-at-the-end-of-the-arc-in-d3-js)? You can get the position from the path attribute and then decide the position of the image. Provide code so that we can help.

Comment: sorry for the late reply you can check the example in this link http://plnkr.co/edit/jD41S59ZttQPj58p
Pac man image needs to rotate and image needs to show end of the arc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tedious, but the following works.

You take the first element of `pieData`, which denotes the blue arc. Then calculate the offset to put the pacman in the right position, using trigonometry. Finally, first translate it so it rotates around its centre, then rotate it the required amount.

I placed it at `radius - 15` from the centre, because that is the middle of the 30 pixel wide arc.

```js
var total_codes = 8;
var remaining_codes = 5;
var issued = total_codes - remaining_codes;
var coloursArray = ["#128ED2", "#dadada"];
var dataset = {
  privileges: [issued, remaining_codes]
};

var width = 160,
  height = 160,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  iconSize = 48;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(coloursArray);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 30)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var pieData = pie(dataset.privileges);
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pieData)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc);
path.transition().duration(750);

svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'pacmancontainer')
  .style('transform', function() {
    // the radius of the center of the arc, also the hypothenuse of a triangle
    var meanRadius = radius - 15;
    var angleRadians = pieData[0].endAngle - Math.PI / 2;
    var xOffset = Math.cos(angleRadians) * meanRadius;
    var yOffset = Math.sin(angleRadians) * meanRadius;
    return " translate(" + xOffset + "px, " + yOffset + "px)";
  })
  .append("image")
  .attr({
    "xlink:href": "http://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckf41wu0g00082c6g6bzer2cc/images/pacman_active_icon.png", //nothing visible
    width: iconSize,
    height: iconSize
  })
  // Make sure the Pacman rotates around its center
  .style('transform-origin', (iconSize / 2) + 'px ' + (iconSize / 2) + 'px')
  .style('transform', function() {
    var angleDegrees = pieData[0].endAngle / (2 * Math.PI) * 360;
    return "translate(-" + (iconSize / 2) + "px, -" + (iconSize / 2) + "px) rotate(" + angleDegrees + "deg)";
  });

svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".0em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "inside")
  .html(function() {
    return "<tspan x='0' dy='0em'>External</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>Privileges</tspan>";
  }); // Add your code here
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruben Helsloot its working fine you saved my time.